# How to use Valentina or DBeaver to load/import a .sql dump file (from the development version of a website) to the local version on my computer?

Tags: django, docker, dbeaver, valentina-studio

I have a .sql file which is a dump of the data coming from the development version of a website. I want to use that data in the local version of the website's Django backend running on my desktop I can see it at localhost:8000 but in the docker-compose.yml file the db is located at port 5432.
What are the steps I need to do using Valentina or DBeaver to load in the data such that that data is what I see in Valentina or DBeaver ?
I've already tried loading the dump through right-clicking the name of the database then choosing load dump from the options but I still don't see any data in the database tables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.